# How do I prevent Firefox's automatic tab discarding?

Tags: firefox

Firefox seems to auto-discard tabs without any words about it since a few new versions.

This behavior does keep RAM usage low, but does hammer the CPU usage quite heavily. On the other hand I do want to keep control on what tabs I'm allowing to hibernate.

I have disabled every extensions I had, so the issue isn't coming from them.

Is there any about:config settings to disable or mitigate (to an extent) Firefox's automatic tab discarding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox discards tabs to free up system resources when it detects memory
on your system is too low, when available memory goes below 340 MB.
The tabs are suspended, rather than discarded, and visiting them again
will bring them up with all entered data.

This means that your computer is starved for memory and/or that too many tabs
are left open for some time.

To disable this option, open `about:config`, type
`browser.tabs.unloadOnLowMemory` and double-click it to set it to "False".

This will mean that memory will still be a problem, and perhaps that
programs will start to partially swap to disk, or that Windows will
start compressing the memory, thus slowing down the computer.

Comment: for some reason this was set to `false` by default on Debian w/ LXDE on a VM. Hmm.